# MySQL PDO not in query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have problem with a query (see below).

I want to get all data from table `abb` and table `amne` that NOT exists in table `abb_elev_mal`.

I want to select everything from table `abb` when **ident** AND **elev_id** isn't found in table `abb_elev_mal`.

*Problem:* wrong data are presented.

Any suggestions?

```
public function get_abb($status, $arskurs, $elev_id, $antal_visningar) {  


     $query = $this->db->prepare("

        SELECT ab.*, aa.*
        FROM `abb` as ab
        INNER JOIN `amne` as aa
            ON ab.amne_id = aa.amne_id      
        WHERE (ab.arskurs = ? AND ab.aktiv = ?)
            AND
               NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT * 
                  FROM `abb_elev_mal` as am 
                  WHERE am.ident = ab.ident AND am.elev_id = ?
               )
        ORDER BY ab.datum DESC
        LIMIT ?");

    $query->bindValue(1, $arskurs,PDO::PARAM_INT);      
    $query->bindValue(2, $status, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
    $query->bindValue(3, $elev_id, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $query->bindValue(4, $antal_visningar, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    try{

        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();

    } catch(PDOException $e){  

        die($e->getMessage());
    }

} // End get_abb
```

**Update:**

```
        SELECT *
        FROM `abb` as ab
        INNER JOIN `amne` as aa
        ON ab.amne_id = aa.amne_id      
        WHERE (ab.arskurs = ? AND ab.aktiv = ?)
        AND ab.ident NOT IN
            (
            SELECT ab.ident
            FROM `abb_elev_mal` 
            WHERE elev_id = ?)
        ORDER BY ab.datum DESC
        LIMIT ?");
```

Same output though.

---

**Update no.2:**

**SELECT 1**

```
SELECT  * 
FROM  `abb` 
WHERE arskurs =8
AND aktiv =1
```

**Output:** 44 results

---

**SELECT 2**

```
SELECT  * 
FROM  `abb_elev_mal` 
WHERE elev_id =934
```

**Output:** 16 results

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM `abb_elev_mal` AS aem
INNER JOIN `abb` AS ab ON aem.ident = ab.ident
WHERE ab.arskurs = 8
AND ab.aktiv = 1
AND aem.elev_id = 934
ORDER BY ab.datum DESC
```

**Output:** same 16 results as *SELECT 2*.

How do I find the 28 results that is "missing" (of the 44 as outputted in SELECT 1)?

Comment: why dont you use `NOT IN (ids)`

Comment: I have tried that, but without success. Like -> `ab.ident NOT IN ()`.

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly in MySQL? And breaking it apart to see where the problem is?

Comment: I have updated my question with some results of queries directly in MySQL. Any suggestions on how to find the "missing" 28 results? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. See below.

```
    $query = $this->db->prepare("

        SELECT *
        FROM `abb` ab
        INNER JOIN `amne` am
        ON ab.amne_id = am.amne_id  
        WHERE ab.ident 
            NOT IN
                (SELECT ident FROM `abb_elev_mal` WHERE elev_id = :elev_id)
        AND arskurs = :arskurs AND aktiv = :status 
        ORDER BY datum DESC
        LIMIT :visningar

    ");

    $query->bindValue(':elev_id', $elev_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);    
    $query->bindValue(':arskurs', $arskurs,PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $query->bindValue(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_INT);      
    $query->bindValue(':visningar', $antal_visningar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```